# Does a header or nav require a container?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap-3

I have seen some examples where there is a container and some where there is not.  I am currently using a container-fluid, but I was curious as to if it is needed and if so, does the class belong on the header element or the nav element?

Answer (score 0):

In the documentation, there is a `.container-fluid` div around the navbar-header, but not around the nav itself. see below:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default">
   **<div class="container-fluid">
      <div class="navbar-header">
         <!-- Content Here -->
      </div>
   **</div>
</nav>
```

Hope this helps!